# Recurring Payments with Website Payments Pro (Payflow Edition)

Tags: paypal

We have an old v1.4.0.1 store and would like to process recurring payments using our current Website Payments Pro (Payflow Edition) setup.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento has a long knowledge base entry for this:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/working-with-recurring-profiles/

Comment: "The current version of Magento supports purchasing a product with the recurring profile using only the PayPal Express Checkout payment method." We don't use Express.

Comment: So you are free to put this as your own answer and mark it as "solution"